For $n,m \geq 1$, when do exist $p_1,\dots,p_n \in S_m$ so that they coordinate-wise map $X$ to $X'$, where $X,X' \subset \{1,\dots,m\}^n, |X|=|X'|$?
Suppose $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $Y = \{1,\dots,m\}^n$. Suppose $p_i \in S_m, i = 1,\dots,n$. Define $P_{p_1,\dots,p_n}: Y \rightarrow Y$ as follows: $\forall y=(y_1,\dots,y_n) \in Y, P(y) = (p_1(y_1),\dots,p_n(y_n))$.
Now, suppose $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}, X'=\{x'_1,\dots,x'_k\} \subset Y, |X| = |X'|, X \cap X' = \emptyset$. When do exist permutations $p_1,\dots,p_n \in S_m$, so that for $P = P_{p_1,\dots,p_n}$, $P(x_i) = x'_i, i = 1,\dots,k$? In other words, when do such permutations exist so that they coordinate-wise map $X$ to $X'$?
An example. Call vectors $x,y \in Y$ independent iff $\forall i, x_i = y_i$. If $X$, $X'$ are sets of pairwise independent vectors, then it's easy to map $X$ to $X'$. The problem is that given a subset $Z \subset Y$, it's NP-hard to find algorithmically a maximal subset $X \subset Z$ of pairwise independent vectors (I need |X| to be big. In this example $|X| \leq m$. I don't strictly need $|X|$ to be equal to $m$, but the closer to $m$, the better. In the general case, the bigger are $|X|=|X'|$, the better, where $X,X'$ are sets such that they can be mapped to each other using such a mapping $P$). On this regard $n,m \leq 64$, and usually $|Z| < 1000$. But depending on the answer of the general question, maybe $Z$ could be constructed in a way to make it easy to search for such subsets $X,X'$ (I can handpick the elements of $Z$).
Thus, I wonder if there are less strict cases when such a mapping exists.
